# Spring Cloud Stream: Default dead letter queue for all bindings

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

In Spring Cloud Stream you can declare a dead letter queue for "input1" binding with:

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input1.consumer.auto-bind-dlq=true
```

If you have n bindings, you have to include n lines with this in application.properties file and that is a bit repetitive.

I want to declare a dead letter queue for all my bindings, something like:

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.default.consumer.auto-bind-dlq=true
```

Is it possible with properties? Is there any way using @Configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider raising an issue - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream. Sounds like a valid request. With that said, I am not a big fan of having multiple bindings (other then inout/output) in a single microservice, so would be equally curious to hear about your use case

Comment: Actually, what version you are using? If you're on the Fishtown.RELEASE (2.1.0) you should be fine with `default`.

Comment: Hi @OlegZhurakousky. Thanks for your help. I can't make it work even in Fishtown.RELEASE. Here is a very simple example project: https://github.com/italktothewind/spring-cloud-examples/tree/dead-letter-queue

Comment: In https://github.com/italktothewind/spring-cloud-examples/blob/dead-letter-queue/src/main/resources/application.properties you have the application.properties with the the two properties, I can only create the DLQ with the commented property.

Comment: You are not using Fishtown. In fact your example is still on boot 1.5

Comment: I created a branch called dead-letter-queue, here is the pom.xml with Fishtown: https://github.com/italktothewind/spring-cloud-examples/blob/dead-letter-queue/pom.xml . Please execute 'git checkout dead-letter-queue', thanks!

Comment: Sorry, i just saw that. I'll post the answer shortly as SO doesn't like long discussions and I do have the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you need to make sure that you use boot 2.1.x since there was a significant improvement in boot with regard to property merge and we are the consumers of that improvement.
Also, the correct property name should be `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.default...`

For example, here is the working configuration:

```
spring.cloud.stream.default.group=myGroup
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input1.destination=myDestination

spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.default.consumer.auto-bind-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.default.consumer.dead-letter-queue-name=myDlx
```

We probably need to clarify this a bit more in documentation

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment (shows the correct configuration). The documentation even today is still wrong: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_rabbitmq_consumer_properties . It says the default pattern is: `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.default.<property>=<value>` (Missing the `consumer` after `default`)